# Sagemaker studio does not load up

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, data-science, amazon-sagemaker

Sagemaker Studio worked flawlessly for me for the first 6 months. Then I started observing this issue. [Screenshot of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ry5Se.png)

The screen holds up at this stage forever. Here's what I have tried:

1. Clearing my cache, even using a different machine. So I don't think the issue lies with the browser or my machine.
2. Pressing 'Clear workspace' in the screenshot above.
3. Shutting down all the apps in my sagemaker domain (excluding the 'default' app). This used to work initially but now this has stopped working all-together.
4. Created a new sagemaker domain with fraction of the files in the previous domain. Still, I see the same error message in the new domain as well.

This is severely affecting my work and I can't find a solution for this anywhere on the internet.

Comment: I see that you have followed the right troubleshooting approach by following step3. Were you able to use SM Studio after following step 4? (my understanding is you have deleted the old domain and created a new one in step4), is that correct?

Comment: Restarting the JupyterServer app (the 'default' app) could help. There were recent updates to the default app, I'd suggest trying it. Also, do you have any packages installed on your EFS, especially `site-packages` inside the `~/.local` folder? That will slow down start up times. In step 4, do you see the error even on a new domain and new user profile before copying over the files?

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this issue before. Restarting the JupyterServer app and clearing out the EFS storage attached to your Studio domain helps.
Also, it is worth checking the JupyterServer logs to see what is causing the issue. Additionally, please make sure to use the latest version of Studio.

Comment: 1. How can we restart the JupyterServer app if Studio itself is not loading?
2. Is there a way to retrieve the code in the stuck Studio domain? Would I need to rewrite my code?